# Non blocking way to return a mono response value

Tags: java, redis, spring-webflux, reactive

I have below code, what is the ideal way to return the value correctly from this method that uses reactive redis operations and is meant to serve as an common api to read a value from redis. I can write some whacky code to manage this but just wondering if there is a cool way that I may be missing, thanks for sharing.

```
public Object getObject(final String key, final String hash) {      
    reactiveRedisCommands.hget(key , field ) //returns Mono<String>     
    .subscribe(             
            new Consumer<String>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(String value) {
                    //String value  is obtained here and converted to object as per type and any additional processing that is required                 

                }
            }); 
    
    return null;// how to return correct value here
}
```

Comment: You can't simple use `reactiveRedisCommands.hget(key, hash).block()`?

Comment: Yeah, that is always there but wondering if can avoid this block as this is an extremely high volume system.

Comment: Since you want to return an Object, not Mono/Future, block is inevitable - you have to wait for the result

Comment: @gdomo is right, there's no better way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The very point of that callback is that the result cannot be provided to the caller; instead, the result will occur some time later.

The usual solution is callback hell: All async methods return `void` and instead take a `Consumer<X>` where `X` is what you'd have ordinarily returned in a non-async world. The problem is that code tends to turn into a spaghetti mess of callbacks piled onto everything.

You signed up for that when you decided to go with an async setup. Usually you don't need to (threads are generally fine).

Project Loom is the name of the work on java to make such things a lot simpler. Very modern JVMs (version 20) have many parts of loom already integrated, but this all happened essentially this year; many frameworks haven't (yet) gotten around to using loom to make this callback hell situation less problematic. So, whilst it's bad news today, it should get better within a year or two.

Until then you have only three options:

1. Start over and ditch async. It's rarely worth it.
2. Have your `getObject` method block until a result is available. This isn't particularly hard to write but makes your `getObject` method an illegal call in any async context (async contexts are not allowed to block!). Generally you get the future and ask the [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) to wait until a response is available. That functionality can also trivially written by making a lock object and using `wait`/`notify` if somehow you want to handroll the functionality. This is usually a very bad idea, you're now mixing sync and async with disastrous results (disastrous as in: Works fine on your dev machine, runs like molasses on production, because you're blocking in async contexts).
3. Rewrite this method into either returning a future, or returning `void` and accepting a `Consumer<String> processor` argument which you pass straight to `subscribe`.